# How to get paypal sale transactions

Tags: php, api, paypal, transactions

I'm trying to pull in orders from paypal into my database. When I say orders, I mean orders from paypal buttons we have in various places.

I've dove into the REST API, but I don't see any API for searching for / listing transactions.  I see a list of payment Resources, but that comes back with count 0.

I also see Sale Transactions in the API but that asks for a single transaction ID.

Is there a way I can periodically get transactions? I know this is possible because we use a tool called Shipstation that grabs new orders from Paypal and brings them into their system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST APIs to do what you are wanting to do. You can use 
[GetPaymentList](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/ListPayments.html) to do this. This is sample code from the PayPal Github PHP homepage. You will need to install and use the [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK).

Comment: This should work *if* the transactions in question were created through the REST APIs. If the transactions were created through "classic" buttons (WPS, EC, or AP) then the REST APIs can't see them.

Comment: Yea, when I call https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#list-payment-resources I don't get any results, but my account has tons of transactions in them.