# Get PayPal Live Transactions

Tags: c#, .net, dll, paypal, transactions

This is an attempt to obtain transactions of my paypal account so I can later insert these into a database for safekeeping on my server. The code below is suppose to get the transactions, between two dates, and return them to me, so I can got through them and obtain the most important information such as email, amount, etc.

It comes back with nothing, when I login to my paypal I can clearly see I have plenty of transactions in this month and the previous month.

What does it to get this list:[image: Transaction List]

```
public static void GetPayment(CommandArgs args)
    {
        var config = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        config.Add("mode", PayPal.Api.BaseConstants.LiveMode);
        config.Add("clientId", "Ady0Bn3J1ik4Bpc29-rTbDYGKaQIY");
        config.Add("clientSecret", "EDSRVBfnRLNsBO4k4ewBBUWnXHjJgWJ");
        config[PayPal.Api.BaseConstants.HttpConnectionTimeoutConfig] = "30000";
        config[PayPal.Api.BaseConstants.HttpConnectionRetryConfig] = "3";

        string accessToken = new PayPal.Api.OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
        args.Player.SendInfoMessage("Access Token Obtained");
        var apiContext = new PayPal.Api.APIContext(accessToken) { Config = config };
        args.Player.SendInfoMessage("Access Token Successful");

        var payments = PayPal.Api.Payment.List(apiContext, null, "", null, "", "", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-25).ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString());
        args.Player.SendInfoMessage("{0}", payments.count);

        //var payment = PayPal.Api.Payment.Get(apiContext, invoices.invoices[0].id);
    }
```

I attempted to use this code for Transactions:

```
            Dictionary<string, string> config = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        config.Add("mode", "live");
        config.Add("account1.apiUsername", "marcus1****");
        config.Add("account1.apiPassword", "3EB8K");
        config.Add("account1.apiSignature", "AFcWx8rxJyxut23nTV");

        PayPal.PayPalAPIInterfaceService.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService search = new PayPal.PayPalAPIInterfaceService.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(config);
        PayPal.PayPalAPIInterfaceService.Model.TransactionSearchReq s = new PayPal.PayPalAPIInterfaceService.Model.TransactionSearchReq();
        s.TransactionSearchRequest.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-25).ToString();
        s.TransactionSearchRequest.EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        var newsearch = search.TransactionSearch(s, "marcus101rr_api1.gmail.com");          
        args.Player.SendInfoMessage("Found: {0}", newsearch.PaymentTransactions.Count());
```

Comment: Try use without parameters like : 
 var paymentList = Payment.List(apiContext); 

I tried here but i need an upgraded account to test in LiveMode.

Comment: Hi, I did as you said and the payment list still comes out 0, I don't even understand Paypal's API because its not a PAYMENT, its a transaction or a history of the transactions I want to collect. The result is below:  https://i.imgur.com/RNjF76u.png

It found no transactions what-so-ever. It is important to note that these transactions are from a "buy/donate" button, I NEED to get those transactions and any/all of them.

Comment: Try use this ClientId and Secret,, works here, probably is something wrong with your configuration in developer site..

Comment: config.Add("clientId", "AUASNhD7YM7dc5Wmc5YE9pEsC0o4eVOyYWO9ezXWBu2XTc63d3Au_s9c-v-U");
            config.Add("clientSecret", "EBq0TRAE-4R9kgCDKzVh09sm1TeNcuY-xJirid7LNtheUh5t5vlOhR0XSHt3");

Comment: this ones are from Sample API from Paypal, here returns data, so your code is right.. :)

Comment: I know about this code, this isn't the problem. Neither the Live nor the Sandbox return ANY Transaction information. However, people are stating if you are using this REST API to obtain your transaction it will not work, this only works for transactions done with the PAYMENT API, and not a button or Credit card.

REFERING TO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482972/how-to-get-paypal-sale-transactions?rq=1